# Why when i move the objects in the Hierarchy to be childs the whole Transform of the objects change?

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is a screenshot of the objects the Platform and the Button when they are not child of the Elevator. And this is how each object transform should be.

[image: Not child]

Then i move drag the objects to be child of the Elevator:

[image: Childs of elevator]

I didn't change anything in the objects transform not rotation and position not scale. I just want to put them under the elevator.

The elevator is the big cube.

```
The terrain Transform: Position and Rotation 0 0 0 Scale 1 1 1

The elevator position: x = 263.05 y = 0.1 z = 148.32
             rotation: x = -2.065 y = 19.039 z = -89.252
             scale x = 0.1 y = 5 z = 2

The button when child: x = -4.0700 y = 0.72499 z = -0.5510
                       x = -36.49  y = 2.436   z = 96.1960
                       x = 0.22    y = 10.13   z = 0.19

When the button is not child: x = 266.106 y = 0.514 z = 146.082
                       x = -0.082  y = 55   z = 6.9
                       x = 0.8    y = 1.6   z = 0.5
```

Comment: non uniform scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because game objects transforms form a [scene graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph) and so the final position of a game object is given by the accumulation of all transforms from the root to the game object.

Thus, When you moved the capsule and the cube to the "elevator" sub-tree, you indirectly set the non-uniform scale that was set in the "elevator" sub-tree root through the transform accumulation process explained above.

EDIT:

To quickly solve your problem create a new game object and set it as the parent of all other objects (elevator, button and platform). I suppose you want to have some animation that animates all objects at the same time. That will do the trick.